# Set 'Enable Slave → Master Access Control' from script console

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I toggle on Jenkins' `Enable Slave -> Master Access Control` (listed under Configure System), control from a Groovy script run using the script console?

I suspect the answer will involve the [MasterKillSwitchConfiguration](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/security/s2m/MasterKillSwitchConfiguration.html) class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is:

```
Jenkins.instance.injector.getInstance(AdminWhitelistRule.class)
    .setMasterKillSwitch(false);
Jenkins.instance.save()
```

Comment: My apologies, this still works. One has to add the package in the groovy script  `import jenkins.security.s2m.*`

Comment: No need to apologise @vikas027. I'd be worried if it didn't work because I was working with Jenkins 2 when I solved this one! Thanks for your comment, hopefully that'll help the next person to stumble across this :).